# Loading big array from file

Tags: php, arrays

I have a really big associative 2d array (about 2.5 million indices in the first dimension) in a file encoded in json. When I loaded this from the file to the array in PHP, it took a long time (about 7 seconds). The size of this array is about 1.5 GB.

What is the best option or how to load this array in good time?

I have thought about giving this array to the cache, but every caching system (memcache, APC) has a limit of 1MB per item.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: 7 seconds to load 1.5Gb seems like a pretty good time to me.

Comment: Why this guys like vote down

Comment: The file has about 100 MB, but the array has about 1.5 GB

Answer (score 0):

How about loading your file for the first time and then split it into multiple subfiles, and keep a track of every file's range of values? When needed, you can check your index for an appropriate range of values and then open the target file and retrieve it.